# Passing xml node to xsl script

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, client-side

I am trying to pass the xml node to xsl script but it is not able to recognise it as xml node.
As a result any operation performed on that node is getting failed below is my code sample

call in stylesheet

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:getDetail( this)"/>
```

xsl script

```
function getDetail( node){
var idpl=1;
var idmt=2;
var kian=7

var racine = node.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
var nmois = racine.selectSingleNode( "root/pl/user[../../@id = '"+idpl+"' and ../@id = '"+idmt+"' and @id = '"+idmois+"' and @ki = '"+kian+"']");
return  nmois.getAttribute('ord')               
}
```

please help.

---

Below is the sample of the xml and xsl

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="doc.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<books>
<book>
<name>Revolution</name>
<qty value="4">1</qty>
</book>
<book>
<name>Life of a pie</name>
<qty value="4">5</qty>
</book>
</books>
```

### XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:user="com.nitish">
<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user" >
function getNode(node){

return node;

}
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/">


<html>
<body>
<h2>Book Details</h2>
<table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" border="1px" cellspacing="20px">
<xsl:variable name="rootNode" select="books"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//book">
<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="user:getNode($rootNode)"/>
</td></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I expect output to be the XML in each cell instead I get only the node text.
puropse of passing XML is to perfoem operations using selectSingleNode and other JS functions
as node is not xml so it fails.

Comment: it fails when doing node.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode  when node is returned withot doing any operations it gives just node text and not the node.

Comment: You will need to tell us exactly which XSLT processor you use. And are you sure you are doing `user:getDetail(this)` and not `user:getDetail(.)`? `user:getDetail(this)` would try to select all `this` element children of the context node and then pass them to that extension script function.

Comment: And why do you need to use script to select some parent nodes and an attribute? You could do all that in pure XSLT/XPath.

Comment: I am using user:getDetail(this) to get the result.

I also tried returning node and printing on the screen and the output shown was simple node text and not the xml nodes.

Comment: Consider to tell us exactly which XSLT processor you use (is that inside IE with MSXML?) and then post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem. And of course so far I continue to think that pure XSLT/XPath with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="../../../root/pl/user[../../@id = 1 and ../@id = 2 and @ki = 7]/@ord"/>` suffices. XPath allows you to navigate the tree, I wouldn't try to use a proprietary approach like calling into script simply to select nodes.

Comment: Martin,I have added the information can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Well with XSLT if you want to copy an XML node to the result tree then you need to use `<xsl:copy-of select="$node"/>` respectively `<xsl:copy-of select="user:getNode($rootNode)"/>`. `xsl:value-of` always constructs a text node with the string value of the selected node, it does not copy the node itself to the output. And that is the same for any node or result tree fragment you have, whether it is a "normal" one simply processed with pure XSLT/XPath or one you hand over to script and then back to XSLT/XPath.

Comment: I tried this but it does not help. I still get the node text on the scree.

Comment: Well if your XML contained a `<p>...</p>` and you copy that to the output the browser of cause also shows the content of the `p` element and not its markup. The same for your `books` element, IE assumes you want to return and render the elements, not to display their markup. It is really not clear what you want to achieve, if you want to serialize your input XML to a string of markup use a solution like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

Comment: I want to fetch the value of qty attribute using selectSingleNode.
return node.selectSingleNode("books/book/qty/@value")